# CheckBox validation and QueryString URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have some problem from my website validation.

I have two columns eg.[id],[name] and checkbox for validation. I need automation fill textbox from URL. but it have some trouble.

For example, I insert `@Context.Request.Query["Name/"id"]` for [Name] textbox and [id] to submit but no tick checkbox validation. It will cause all the textbox data disappear.

If no insert `Context.Request.Query["Name/"id"]` for [Name] textbox and [id] to submit but no tick checkbox validation.it will save data in textbox.

Gif for reference - this is insert `Context.Request.Query["Name/"id"]`:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGrwz.gif

Here is my target. when no tick and pop the error. the column still have data save.
GIF2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGmHU.gif

Controller

```
public class CheckBoxRequired : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // get the entered value
        var student = (UserViewModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

        // Check whether the IsAccepted is selected or not.
        if (student.IsAccepted == false)
        { 
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage == null ? "Please checked the checkbox" ErrorMessage); 
        }

        return  ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}

public IActionResult CreateUser()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateUser(UserViewModel user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // after validation success, create a UserClass instance based on the ViewModel, and insert the "newuser" into database.
        var newuser = new UserClass();
        newuser.ID = user.ID;
        newuser.Name = user.Name;       

        // save the newuser into the database via dbcontext
        _dbcontext.UserClass.Add(newuser);
        _dbcontext.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.UserViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CreateUser";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
} 

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form asp-action="CreateUser">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ID" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ID" class="form-control"value="@Context.Request.Query["ID"]" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" value="@Context.Request.Query["Name"]"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="IsAccepted" /> 
                </label>
                <span asp-validation-for="IsAccepted" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Models

```
public class UserViewModel
{
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Entry ID")]
     public int ID { get; set; }
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Entry Name")]
     public string Name { get; set; } 
     //use custom validation method
     [CheckBoxRequired(ErrorMessage ="Please checked the items")]
     public bool IsAccepted { get; set; } 
}
```

Can anybody help and give advise? Thanks

Comment: You mean the data Will be cleared after the submit? Have you checked the url after the submit? Seems that your action is returning a view() without query string values.

Comment: Yes!i want to keep the data in column after submit when I forget tick the checkbox.
But when I add the query string it will cause can not preserve data in column after submit.Do you have any idea?thans

Comment: can you post here what is the url after your submit?

Comment: Is redirect to other page

Comment: I didn't understand. Is redirected to another page? So why do you want to preserve data if it is not the same page? I want to know which url appears if you submit without check the box.

Comment: I need automation fill textbox from URL for user no need to manually input the data and prevent their entry wrong information in to column.so when I automation fill in textbox it part is ok  but when I forget to tick checkbox validation after submit. It will clear my data in column .Look like gif1. When  I submit it will redirect to local host/43349/HomePage. Thanks you sooooo much

Comment: use   return View(user) in the post instead of return view(). And change your form to be like this   <form action="@Url.Action("CreateUser", "user")?@(Request.QueryString)" method="post">.   Where the second parameter user is your controller name. You didnt inform it.

Comment: hello Silva, thanks for your teaching! it is very useful for me to use another way replace @Context.Request.Query.but it is not work. Also, i have one controller only. thanks